# Output of this program using different scoping/binding rules and parameter-passing?

Tags: binding, scope, parameter-passing, higher-order-functions

This is a (really) hard exercise for my next exam. It's intended for scoping, binding and parameter-passing rules undestanding. I can't figure out even the first 3 numbers outputted, this is driving me crazy.

***What is the output of this C-like program with dynamic scope, shallow binding and expression evaluation from left to right?***

```
1 A : {
2
3    int x = 5;
4    int y = 7;
5
6    proc P(ref int y, valueresult int z, int R(name int)) {
7       z = y-- + R(++x + ++y);
8       write(x, y, z);
9       z = R(z++);
10   }
11
12   B : {
13
14      int x = 3;
15
16      int Q(name int w) {
17           return (w + x++ + y++);
18      }
19
20      P(x, y, Q); // start here
21      write(y++, x++);
22   }
23
24   write(y, x);
25
26 }
```

Comment: I see unbalanced brackets. Is line 21 in C:?

Comment: @philosodad: fixed and cleaned, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A.x = 5

A.y = 7

B.x = 3

Calls P(3, 7, Q) - Inside P, y is a ref to B.x, which value is 3, z is 7. Due to dynamic scope, inside P, x is B.x.

Inside P, in the first instruction, we have the post-decrement y-- evaluated first, so the evaluated value would be 3 and B.x will change to 2.

R is called by name, so the return (w + x++ + y++) will become return ++x + ++y + x++ + y++. The entire first expression is expanded to something equivalent to z = y-- + (++x + ++y + x++ + y++).

In the expression ++x + ++y + x++ + y++, we have a pre-increment ++x, which will change B.x to 3 and give 3 as result. The ++y will change B.x to 4 and evaluate 4. The x++ will evaluate to 4 and change to 5 and the y++ will evaluate to 5 and change to 6.

So the returned value from Q is 3 + 4 + 4 + 5 = 16. This will be added to the previous z-- value which is 3, so 19 will be assigned to z and B.x will be 6.

The write will print x which is due to dynamic scope B.x, so will print 6. The y is a reference to the same B.x, so will print 6. The z is 19. **So it will print 6, 6, 19**.

In the third instruction of the P, we have z = R(z++) which due to call by name will expand to something equivalent to z = (z++ + x++ + y++).

So we get the z value, which is 19 and increment to 20 (post-increment). Add it to the value of B.x (6) and change B.x to 7. Add the 7 from y and increment y (which is B.x) to 8.
So z = 19 + 6 + 7 = 32. B.x is 8.

Due to the valueresult of z, the A.y will be changed to 32.

Outside P, the write(y++, x++) will get the A.y value, which is 32 and print it. Then A.y will change to 33. B.x which is 8 will be printed and changed to 9. **So it will print 32, 8**.

Finally, the A.y will be printed (its value is 33). The A.x will be printed, which is 5. **So it will print 33, 5**.

Concluding, the program prints **6, 6, 19, 32, 8, 33, 5**.

Comment: Yeah... Thank you, too. That was a very challenging exercise. :)

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807946/exercise-misunderstood-static-scope-parameter-passing-by-name-result? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up with - in a line-by-line trace:

```
   before P(x,y,Q)                          A.x = 5 A.y = 7  B.x = 3
      entering P                            A.x = 5 A.y = 7  B.x = 3 y = 3 z = 7
      before z = y-- + R(++x + ++y)         A.x = 5 A.y = 7  B.x = 3 y = 3 z = 7
         entering R                  w = 9  A.x = 6 A.y = 7  B.x = 3
            return (w + x++ + y++)
         leaving R                   w = 9  A.x = 6 A.y = 8  B.x = 4 returns 19
      after z = y-- + R(++x + ++y)          A.x = 6 A.y = 8  B.x = 4 y = 4 z = 22
      write(x, y, z)
```

6 4 22

```
      before z = R(z++)                     A.x = 6 A.y = 8  B.x = 4 y = 4 z = 22
         entering R                  w = 22 A.x = 6 A.y = 8  B.x = 4
            return (w + x++ + y++)
         leaving R                   w = 22 A.x = 6 A.y = 9  B.x = 5 returns 34
      after z = R(z++)                      A.x = 6 A.y = 9  B.x = 5 y = 5 z = 34
   after P(x,y,Q)                           A.x = 6 A.y = 34 B.x = 5
   write(y++, x++)
```

34 5

```
   after write(y++,x++)                     A.x = 6 A.y = 35 B.x = 6
   write(y, x)
```

35 6

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong. The solution states that the first 3 numbers are: 6, 6, 19!